# issues finding public folder when requiring sinatra/base

Tags: ruby, sinatra, haml

I have found that in my Sinatra app, when I `require 'sinatra'`, I can access my public folder as expected, but when I `require 'sinatra/base'` I can't.  Here is my relevant code (which works until I change to `/base`):

**config.ru**

```
root = ::File.dirname(__FILE__)
require ::File.join( root, 'app' )
run MyApp.new
```

**app.rb**

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra/namespace'
require 'haml'

class MyApp < Sinatra::Application
  # ...
end

require_relative 'models/init'
require_relative 'helpers/init'
require_relative 'routes/init'
```

**script.haml**

```
%script(type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js")
%script(type="text/javascript" src="/js/table.js")
%link(rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/table.css")
```

And yes, I have the correct directory structure in place. Like I said, it works using `require sinatra`.  Anyone know why this is occurring and what I can do to fix it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Requiring `Sinatra::Base` does not set any of the default [configuration settings](http://www.sinatrarb.com/configuration.html) that requiring `Sinatra` does. You'll need to `set :public_folder ...` to a suitable value yourself, e.g:

```
set :public_folder, 'public'
```

Comment: Thanks! That was what it was, and I didn't realize that difference between the two methods of requiring Sinatra. Note, you need a comma following `:public`.

Comment: Oops, sorry about the comma - fixed

Comment: It solved my problem, thank you very much!
BTW, the syntax has changed to
 
`set :public_folder`